# How does ls [[:punct:]]* work?

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I am learning bash. Currently, I have a file called **_something.txt** and when I use:

```
ls [[:punct:]]*
```

I get the following error:

```
ls: invalid option -- 'V'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a name in your current directory that starts with a dash (`-`), this name is mistaken for an option to `ls`.

Use `--` to delimit the actual options from the operands when you call `ls` to avoid this:

```
ls -- [[:punct:]]*
```

The double dash (`--`) ends the options list.

Answer (score 3):

You have a file whose name starts with a dash (`-`).

Try `ls -d ./-*` to see it